# Java - Selenium - Div elements beyond page view are not loaded even after scroll into view

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

We have been struggling with this a lot. We have a page with div elements.

The Xpath for the elements in incremental for e.g.
tr[2]/td[4],tr[7]/td[4],tr[12]/td[4],tr[17]/td[4],tr[22]/td[4],.....

Now the problem here is when we run a loop for the above elements, it just shows elements upto the 4th iteration. If there are more items, we are not able to get those elements as they are only visible after they are brought into view by scrolling manually.

Programmatic scrolling shows the view as plain white without any elements on it.

So basically the page below the visibility is blank. When we scroll the elements appear slowly.

Is there any way that we can get all elements from that table without scrolling? My understanding is that even though these elements are not visible they are still a part of the page as they become visible after scroll.

We tried scroll into view of the elements, but get the Nosuchelementfound exception.

we tried using keyboard down arrow key to make the down items visible but when the rows are considerable high in numbers, the table screen becomes white and we again get the same Nosuchelementfound exception.

````
                            while (1<2) {
                                WebElement pkgtype = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sheet1\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr["+ cmtab +"]/td[6]"));
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", pkgtype);
                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                String cmpk = pkgtype.getAttribute("innerHTML");

                                if(cmpk.equals(temppk)) {
                                    pkgtype.click();
                                    try {
                                    pkgtype.click();
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e) {

                                    }
                                    driver.findElement(By.id("_editInput0")).sendKeys(mPkgType);


                                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"sheet1\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr["+ cmtab +"]/td[8]")).click();
                                    cmtab = cmtab + 5;
                                }

                            }

                            }
                            catch(Exception e) {

                            }```
````

Comment: It sounds like the page is loading data as you scroll.  The only way to get the full data is to continually scroll until your element is loaded onto the page.  If you know your element is going to be there, you can wrap the check for the element in a loop where you continue scrolling until it's found.  If the page has a limited number of elements, you could also scroll until the size of the data stops increasing.

Comment: Hello @ejdebruin,
It would be great if you can give some example code which shows scroll until element is found.

Comment: @PrashantVaingankar found any solution?